# hg add -X not working

Tags: mercurial

I'd like to `hg add` excluding files that begin with `._`, or even better exclude all hidden files.

It's not working, it's just completely ignoring my -X option.

I tried the following:

```
hg add -n -X '._*'
hg add -n -X '*._*'
```

and just to be sure also:

```
hg add -n -X '*.*'
```

nothing. It's just as if I didn't `-X` at all.

I've tried both with hg 1.4.3 and hg 1.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This works on Windows and Mercurial 1.5.3; things may be different for Unix if that's what you're using).

You have the file spec. in single quotes; it should be double quotes:

```
hg add -X "._*"
```

Another way would be to add an entry to your [.hgignore](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) file, for example:

```
 syntax: glob
 ._*
```

Comment: I'll have a look at `.hgignore` because it seems it should do it, thanks :) (btw: I'm using OSX)